# Understanding an Example of a Categorical Cokernel in $\mathbf{Ab}$

Tags: category-theory

From pg. 61 of *Categories for the Working Mathematician*:

[image]

**Question:** In the example given for $\mathbf{Ab}$, how do we know that $hf = 0$ and $uf = 0$ (i.e., that these composites are *zero arrows*)?

Comment: There is no example here, just a definition. Unless I misunderstand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example of abelian groups, $a = A$, $b = B$, $f = f$, $e = B/f(A)$, and $u = (B\to B/f(A))$; there is no $h$. In the diagram, $h$ is zero *by assumption*, the cokernel $u : b\to e$ is defined such that *if* you have a morphism $h : b\to c$ with $hf = 0$, *then* there is a unique $h' : e\to c$ with $h = h' u$.

To see that $uf = 0$ in the example, take $a\in A$. Then $a$ is mapped to $f(a)\in B$ under $f$, and $f(a)$ is mapped to the coset $f(a) + f(A)$ under $u$. But since $f(a)\in f(A) = \{b\in B\mid b = f(a),\textrm{ such that }a\in A\}$, $f(a) + f(A) = 0 + f(A)$, which is the zero element in $B/f(A)$. Thus, $uf(a) = 0 + f(A)$ for all $a\in A$, so that $uf = 0$.

Comment: Is $im (f)$ serving as the null object here?

Comment: No, the zero object in $\mathsf{Ab}$ is the trivial group.

Comment: Again staying in the setting of  $\mathbf{Ab}$, does this whole setup imply that $h'$ takes all elements of $e = B/f(A)$ to the identity of $c$?

Comment: No. Take $h : B\to c$ to be the cokernel of $f$ again: that is, $h : B\to B/f(A)$ is also the natural quotient map. $h'$ is the unique map $h' : B/f(A)\to B/f(A)$ such that $h' u = h = u$. Because $u$ is surjective (or in categorical terms, $u$ is an epimorphism), it follows that $h' = id_{B/f(A)}$. In this case, $h'$ takes only the identity of $B/f(A)$ to the identity of $c = B/f(A)$. However, $hf$ must take all elements of $A$ to the identity of $c$ (this is exactly the assumption that $hf$ is the zero morphism).

Comment: Ok, I think I got it now: but we can say that $f(A) \subset h(f(A))$, in general -- correct?

Comment: Not really - $f(A)\subseteq B$, but $h(f(A))\subseteq c$ (so in general it doesn't make sense to say one is a subset of the other). The hypothesis that $hf = 0$ ensures that $h(f(A))\subseteq c$ consists of only the identity element.

Comment: Yes -- I was confused. But what about $f(A) \subset Ker(h)$? Can we say this?

Comment: $f(A)\subseteq\ker h$ is exactly the hypothesis that $hf = 0$, so yes.

Answer (score 1):

So, $f:A\to B$ followed by the quotient map $\pi:B\to B/{\rm im}f$ compose to zero, as for any $a\in A$, $f(a)\in{\rm im}f$ and hence $\pi(f(a))=0$.

Now, if any $h:B\to C$ gives $h(f(a))=0$ for all $a$, it exactly means that $h$ vanishes on ${\rm im}f$, i.e. factors through $B/{\rm im}f$.